# Right align child div to parent using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I adjust my css to have the child div (popup like menu) right align to the parent div which is a button in this case?

Right now i have this

[image]

and im trying to make it look like this....

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/pqw2jeb9/

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menuRoot {
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 90;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">
    Hi
    <div role="menu" class="menuRoot">
      <div>
        <!-- Activator -->
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="relative p-1 duration-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Paret Button</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <!-- Popup -->
        <div class="popup">
          <button type="button" class="relative p-1 duration-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Child Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    Great
  </div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a lot, I remembered I'm Arabic and I did this too much, my lovely language starts from right to left so just add `dir="rtl"` to menu root, then add `dir="ltr"` to the popup.

so the popup's Xaxis changed to the right while it was on the left, when adding extra content the width will increase to the right and the `dir="ltr"` to the popup to just override the parent's direction.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menuRoot {
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 90;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box d">
    Hi
    <div role="menu" class="menuRoot" dir="rtl">
      <div>
        <!-- Activator -->
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="relative p-1 duration-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Paret Button</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Overlay -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        <!-- Popup -->
        <div dir="ltr" class="popup">
          <button type="button" class="relative p-1 duration-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Child Button 1</button>
          <button type="button" class="relative p-1 duration-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Child Button 2</button>
          <button type="button" class="relative p-1 duration-300 rounded-full hover:bg-gray-200">Child Button 3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    Great
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but it makes all child items dir that way and screws up a ton of menu items and content.

Comment: well, while there's one more solution by JS, can you upload the menu to here or give jsfiddle link, I'll re-flip the content to be normal. Or you can try the edit I'll submit it may help, I'm not sure, but I promise if you give me the menu I'll solve it

Comment: I think it will work, I tried to add content to let you see and changed the box size, anyway you just have to set the Root `dir="rtl"`, and the popup _or whatever you want inside the root_ to `dir="ltr"`.